# How do we allow a certain mac address in a FORWARD chain through iptables?

Tags: server, firewall, iptables

I set the iptables rules in default.

```
# IPTABLES IN DEFAULT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

How will allow a certain mac address in a forward chain?
I tried this code:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source 00:00:00:00:00:a00 -j ACCEPT
```

but it won't work.

When I set all iptables chain by default to ACCEPT and block a certain mac address will work.

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m mac --mac-source 00:00:00:00:00:00 -j DROP
```